# Can I install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net

Can I install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

Per the readme found on this page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en

Comment: @Paul - No problem! Hey, if you could accept this as an answer, I would much appreciate it. (Click the green checkmark on the left side of the question.) Thank you!